# Getting object has no attribute error when creating admin reg in django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have been getting this error only when creating my first user, which is suppose to become the admin user. How can i fix this?

Error:

```
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/Johnny/Desktop/pythondjango/django/user_dashboard/apps/login/views.py", line 18, in register
    regstatus = User.userManager.register(**request.POST)
  File "/Users/Johnny/Desktop/pythondjango/django/user_dashboard/apps/login/models.py", line 43, in register
    new_user.update(user_level='admin')
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'update'
```

code: 
views.py

```
def register(request):
    regstatus = User.userManager.register(**request.POST)
if regstatus[0]:
    request.session['user_id'] = regstatus[1]
    return redirect(reverse('dashboard:index'))
else:
    for message in regstatus[1]:
        messages.warning(request, message)
    return redirect(reverse('login:index'))
```

models.py:

```
new_user = self.create(email=email, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, password=pw_hash)
    # Make first registered user an admin
    if new_user.id == 1:
        new_user.update(user_level='admin')
    return (True, new_user.id)
```

These two snippets of code is where my errors are currently happening. Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to change a obj's field value, you should just assign it as attribute and then call `.save()` on it.

```
new_user.user_level = 'admin'
new_user.save()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to make the first created user the admin, all you need is

```
User.objects.filter(id=1).update(user_level='admin')
```

I assume you are not using django.contrib.auth.models.User because that does not haev a user_level field. If you want to fix that particular bit of code, you have pasted

```
new_user = self.create(email=email, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, password=pw_hash)

# Make first registered user an admin
if new_user.id == 1:
    new_user.user_level='admin')
    new_user.save()
return (True, new_user.id)
```

but really you are better off using one of the tried and tested django regsitration/user management packages. django-allauth can be highly recommended (I have no affiliations with it)

Comment: awesome, I tried to rate you all, but am not ranked 15 yet.

Answer (score 1):

default django User deosnot have a user_level i assume you need a user who can login to default admin-site in django it is "superuser" so make user with superuser and have staff acces so do like this

```
user = User.objects.get(id=1)
user.is_staff = True
user.is_superuser = True
user.save()
```

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot. New to django.

Comment: Please look this  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ this is the best  place to refer django is very simple. Spend some time play with it